# Remote Mongo DB connection through shell scripts

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, connection, sh

I have to establish connection to Remote mongo database through shell script and execute a js file with mongo queries  Please help me with the commands..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

```
 mongo mongodb://user:<pass>@<ip>:27017/test&authSource=admin myjsfile.js
```